# Dynamic mic to XLR input

Tags: microphone, mixer, amplifier

I bought [this ammoon F4 mixer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DXR5FN8) on Amazon, and I need help connecting a dynamic microphone to it.
The mic channels have XLR and TRS inputs. The TRS is marked "LINE" and it works only with line signal from amlified source (like player or so). When I connect the microphone, I can't get any output. When I use TRS to XLR cable to connect the mic to the XLR input, it also doesn't work. I also tried every possible combination of connecting positive and negative wires of the mic to the XLR pins, still no output.

So, am I doing something wrong? Or did I get a mix without microphone preamplifier? If so, is there any small preamp in the size of TRS to XLR powered by phantom? (so it won't take much space and don't need another power brick)
Thanks.

//edit:
It's unbranded dynamic microphone with 1/4 inch jack, it works fine with mic input on my PC, when using a 1/4 inch to 3.5mm adapter.

//edit2:
I had some mics with 3.5mm jack that I used few year ago on my PC for skype calls and decided to use them with 3.5 to 1/4" jack adapter. The first is KONIG KN-MIC10 and it works fine with this mix. The second is Trust Starzz and it has the same issue, not working. Maybe the mix works only with some dynamic mics?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79742/discussion-on-question-by-adam-jezek-dynamic-mic-to-xlr-input).

Answer (score 2):

So, You have a microphone that works on your PC but not this mixer. And other mics that DO work on this mixer..?

I hate to add questions that are better suited comments, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Have you tried cranking the input gain on your mixer with the dynamic mic in question? Since it sounds like your friends mixer has an extra boost for this purpose, maybe that's all you need?
How are you checking that the mixer is getting signal from the mic? Just because the LEDs on the mixer don't flicker doesn't mean there isn't a tiny signal being passed in. Try going from mic to mixer to your PC. Then once it's in a recording app or DAW you can boost it with software.
The picture you show of the mic's jack does not suggest it is balanced. So, the gist of your OP is probably not relevant. (Unless I'm missing something.)
There are adapters for 1/4 inch to XLR.

Have you tried plugging the mic into the FX return? Just for giggles? The signal returned to this jack is probably expected by the device to be line level, so if the mic doesn't have the umph to do anything at the mic input, it probably won't do anything at the FX return. But still... I always try everything.

To answer the question you had about phantom powered pre amps, yes they exist. The Cloud Microphones CL-1 Cloudlifter 1-channel Mic Activator costs about $150. You could go this route, but if you have the money for of these gizmos, you're better off buying a better mic.

There is some debate about which is the most important piece of gear in a studio or field recorder. Some say put your money into the microphone, others say put it into the pre amp. For people on a budget, I say go with the best mic you can afford.

I hope some part of this is helpful. And good luck.